# nginx - application url redirection/rewrite

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite, url

I've got a simple nginx server (myaddress.com) serving my applications using locations.

I added a new proxied site: /myApp/ and when I try to access it - web browser is getting 404 errors trying to fetch data directly from myaddress.com/* instead of myaddress.com/myApp/*. So if I have an app using image.jpg the browser would try to fetch myaddress.com/image.jpg instead of myaddress.com/myApp/image.jpg

I tried to play with nginx rewrite:

- rewrite /myApp/(.*) /$1  break;
- rewrite ^(.*) /myApp/$1 last;
- rewrite ^(.*) /myApp/$1 permanent;
- rewrite ^(.*) https://$host/myApp/$1 permanent;
- rewrite ^/$ /myApp/$1 last ;
- rewrite myaddress.com/ myaddress.com/myApp/ break;

But it looks like I found several ways to make it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your applications so that they refer to resources using correct URLs. Anything else is problem prone and should be avoided.

Comment: I'd love to but i'm not developing that app, just using it. And therefore I'm afraid that's not an option... :(